# Freemaker The following has evaluated to null or missing

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to build a process in topdesk/freemaker that gets the expected arrival date from a visitor using the "get" [https://obscured.topdesk.net/tas/api/visitors/${unid}](https://obscured.topdesk.net/tas/api/visitors/$%7Bunid%7D) in step 1.

In step 2 I'm to get the data stored in step 1 and check if the expected arrival is the same a today using the following:

${_responses.GetVisitorData.body.expectedArival}["dd MMMM yyyy"] == now?string["dd MMMM yyyy"]

But when I run it, it gives me the following error:
[2021-10-19T07:18:44.947659300Z] Error while processing FreeMarker template: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> _responses.GetVisitorData.body.verwachteaankomst  [in template "action sequence" at line 1, column 3]

While step 1 does seem to be storing the data correctly:
[2021-10-19T07:18:44.947659300Z] Storing response data
[2021-10-19T07:18:44.947659300Z] Successfully finished step 'GetVisitorData'

I'm really lost as to why it evaluates to null.
Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you actually have `verwachteaankomst`, and not `expectedArival` (and therefore the typo in the last, the single `r`, doesn't matter). But shouldn't that be `verwachteAankomst`, with the capital `A`?

Comment: You example is strange as it has raw text that looks like FTL. If you are inside an `#if`, `#assign`, or some other directive, you are already in expression mode, and `${}` is an error in that context.

Comment: Last not least, a less painful way of comparing the date part of two timestamp is this: `ts1?date?iso_local == ts2?date?iso_local`. (That's as of 2.3.31; future versions will probably expand date/time features.) Or, if you are sure that both values are date-only, then you can just compare them like `date1 == date2`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [TOPdesk API documentation for visitor registration](https://developers.topdesk.com/explorer/?page=visitors#/Visitors/get), the expected arrival date/time is part of a subset called visit:
[image: GET visitor API result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyOOS.png)

So, if you want to retrieve the expectedArrival date you need to use:
${_responses.GetVisitorData.body.**visit**.expectedArival}

Since expectedArival only occurs in the subset and not in the main category, ${_responses.GetVisitorData.body.expectedArival} would evaluate to null, since it doesn't exist.